# Problem installing git subrepo on MacOs bash 5

Tags: bash, git, macos, macos-high-sierra

I was trying to install git subrepo on MacOs with bash 5.0.18 installed. When I source .bashrc, I get error message :

> The git-subrepo command requires that 'Bash 4+' is installed. It
> doesn't need to be your shell, but it must be in your PATH. You appear
> to be on macOS. Try: 'brew install bash'. This will not change your
> user shell, it just installs 'Bash 5.x'.

Is git subrepo not compatible with bash 5 or is there any solution to make it work?

https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently, I can install it using brew with less hassle:

```
brew install git-subrepo
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be a `PATH` issue, as illustrated by [`ingydotnet/git-subrepo` issue 463](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo/issues/463)

> I realized there was a part of my path not being specified which caused this issue.